# RAID 10 + bcache + LVM

Tags: linux, cache, lvm, software-raid, raid10

I'm planning to setup a new RAID 10 array using Linux mdadm with bcache and LVM. The way I think about it is that first I create the RAID 10 array then I use the array as a backing device for bcache then the resulting device is used to create a PV. Is this the right order of doing this? Or the bcache should be defined for each LVs?

Thanks!